# Instances for SignalR counter missing in performance monitor

Tags: .net-core, signalr, performance-monitor

I have installed SignalR.exe from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils namespace. After that, I deployed my .NET core application in IIS in my local computer. I have added "IUSR" user in performance monitor users group.

When I try to add SignalR counter, no instance is available as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Kindly guide me how I can view performance counter for SignalR.